# Existence of Lebesgue integral on limit domain

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose that for some $a,b \in \mathbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$ with $a < b$, a function $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb R$ is continuous (but possibly unbounded). Moreover, there exists $L \in \mathbb R$ such that for all decreasing sequences $a_n \to a$ and increasing sequences $b_n \to b$,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int\limits_{[a_n,b_n]} f(x) dx = L.$$

Can I conclude that the Lebesgue integral $\int\limits_{(a,b)} f(x) dx$ exists?

To me, the setup seems similar to Fatou's Lemma, but with a special domain, without non-negativity, and with this "limit exists" condition. But I can't see how / whether the pieces fit together. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about that. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $f(x)=\frac 1 x \sin (\frac 1 x)$ on $(0,1)$. Then the hypothesis holds with $L=\int_1^{\infty} \frac {\sin x} xdx$ but $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable. [Make the substitution $y=\frac 1 x $ for the proof].

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @JohnSturm perhaps you could accept the answer?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Sorry, I'm new here.